# What mean @:@ in Razor syntax?

Tags: razor

Maybe stupid question, but i didn't find what it mean.

code example:

```
@if (isSomething ) {
    @:@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/some-scripts")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems redundant. The `@:` specifies literal content, but then `@` takes you back into the server code context. It should work the same as:

```
@if (isSomething ) {
  Scripts.Render("~/scripts/some-scripts")
}
```